# Grunt URL rewrite in Angular application on page reload

Tags: javascript, angular, gruntjs, legacy

Here's what the livereload block looks like in Grunt file:

```
livereload: {
  options: {
    open: true,
    middleware: function(connect, options, middleware) {
      var optBase = typeof options.base === "string" 
        ? [options.base] 
        : options.base;

      return [
        [
          require("connect-modrewrite")(["!(\\..+)$ / [L]"])
        ].concat(
          optBase.map(function(path) { return connect.static(path); })
        ),
        connect.static(".tmp"),
        connect().use("/bower_components", connect.static("./bower_components")),
        connect().use("/app/styles", connect.static("./app/styles")),
        connect.static(appConfig.app)
      ];
    }
  }
}
```

However, if my URL has a '.' (period) in it, Grunt fails to reload the page. I am using HTML5 Mode in my Angular app and that works fine.

Could I please know what part of

```
[
  require("connect-modrewrite")(["!(\\..+)$ / [L]"])
].concat(
  optBase.map(function (path) { return connect.static(path); })
)
```

is causing it to fail and how do I fix this?

Note: It fails only on page reload. The first time I visit the route it works, then if I hit refresh it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could I please know what part of [this snippet] is causing it to fail and how do I fix this?

The `connect-modrewrite` rule here appears to be intended for rewriting non-static-asset URLs only.

```js
[
  require("connect-modrewrite")(["!(\\..+)$ / [L]"])
].concat(
  optBase.map(function (path) { return connect.static(path); })
)
```

The rule passed in here, `"!(\\..+)$ / [L]"`, is an [inverted URL matching rule](https://github.com/tinganho/connect-modrewrite#inverted-url-matching) to rewrite all URLs that *don't* contain a period and one or more characters back to the base URL (`/`). So, if your routes include a period, they will not be rewritten... this is why it fails when live reload runs.

One suggestion to remedy this is to more explicitly avoid rewrites for requests to static assets:

```js
    require("connect-modrewrite")([
      '!\\.html|\\.js|\\.svg|\\.css|'
      + '\\.scss.*|\\.woff.*|\\.gif.*|\\.png$ '
      // etc...
      + '/ [L]'
    ])
```

Notice that this rule also begins with an exclamation point (`!`). Instead of relying solely on the presence of a period, it more explicitly targets URLs that don't include certain file extensions-- along with the period! (:

Note: [code for the suggestion was found on searchcode.com here](https://searchcode.com/file/284650461/Gruntfile.js/)

I hope this helps! HMU with any questions, corrections, or well actually-s.